# Like gating on a facebook website

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to do Like-Gating for our application. The application is an external website using facebook connect.

I have looked around the documentation and found that you generally do this using the signed-request data you receive from facebook. But seems like that data is only sent by facebook if the app is a facebook page. Correct me if I am wrong.

How can acheive the same result on a external website using facebook connect?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can approximate this functionality by using the facebook Javascript API. Use [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) to subscribe to an event when the Like button (in a [Like Box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)) is pressed, and then redirect the user to the gated content with that event.

I have done this before in real-world web apps, and it works well. I can post some of that code as an example, if you need it. The event you want to listen for is the `edge.create` event.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but [the functionality you're asking for](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/) is only available on facebook.com with the exception of Pages, and thus you cannot like gate your website.